# How to catch the presence of characters in a string input `std::stof`?

Tags: c++

I want to take an input from the user which is a float value, but I want to re-prompt the user if they enter something like `10.00abcd` i.e. say the `abcd` was typed in accidentally. However, in the code I have now, the `std::stof()` functions returns `10.00` when the input is `10.00abcd`. How can I catch this problem so that I can reprompt the user to enter a *pure* float string?

```cpp
while (true) {
        std::cout << variableName << ": ";
        std::string inp;
        std::cin >> inp;
        try {
            float val = std::stof(inp);
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
            return val;
        } catch (...) {
            // Want to get here if inp = "10.00abcd"
            std::cout << "Please enter float value only.\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: or [Why does std::stof not throw when passed an argument it cannot convert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443074/why-does-stdstof-not-throw-when-passed-an-argument-it-cannot-convert)

Comment: Check the "inp" input string for all characters of it. Library function - isdigit() can help

Comment: Begin by **reading its documentation**. The second argument to [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) will help you here.